# jquery onclick expand div and change text inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with my script where i click the H3 it will expand and only change the first text in span no matter if i click the second H3. After i wanna collapse it , it doesn't change back to the original text.
What should i use ? TQ

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".pad").hide();

      //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
      jQuery(".heading").click(function()
      {
        jQuery(this).next(".pad").slideToggle(500);
        jQuery('#span1).html('&#8743;')
      });
    });
    </script>

<h3 class="heading">text1<span id="span1" style="float:right;">&#8744;</span></h3>
<div id="occ" class="pad">
content
</div>
<h3 class="heading">Text2<span id="span1" style="float:right;">&#8744;</span></h3>

<div id="tech" class="pad">
content
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo (missing closing `'`) in `jQuery('#span1).html('&#8743;')`

Comment: You forgot to close `'` in `jQuery('span)`

Comment: You have type error & duplicate ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a toggle function for the arrows. As this can't be done with the html codes you need to use ids so you can target them specifically here is the jquery you need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pad').hide();
    $('.heading').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.pad').slideToggle();
        if($(this).find('.span1').attr('id') == 'yes') {
            $(this).find('.span1').attr('id', '').html('&#8744;');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.span1').attr('id', 'yes').html('&#8743;');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/5xueU/2/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting #span1, it's going to return only the first instance of that in your document every time. IDs must be unique. Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".pad").hide();

  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".heading").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".pad").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).find("span").html('&#8743;')
  });
});
</script>

<h3 class="heading">text1<span id="span1" style="float:right;">&#8744;</span></h3>
<div id="occ" class="pad">
content
</div>
<h3 class="heading">Text2<span id="span2" style="float:right;">&#8744;</span></h3>

<div id="tech" class="pad">
content
</div>
```

To toggle the arrows back, try checking for the visibility of the `.pad` element:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/W6nBG/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".pad").hide();

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
        var $pad = $(this).next(".pad");
        var $arrow = $(this).find("span");
        if ($pad.is(':visible')) {
            $arrow.html('&#8744;');
        } else {
            $arrow.html('&#8743;');
        }
        $pad.slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the duplicate Id deceleration then :)

Comment: ok i have change my span into class but the same name. so , now how do i reset to default text after i click to collapse it ?

Comment: @TJ: you say: "IDs must be unique" but your code doesn't show this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pad").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".heading").click(function()
        $heading = $(this); 
        $(this).next(".pad").slideToggle(500,function() {
            var sign = $(this).is(':visible') ? '&#8743;' : '&#8744;';
            $heading.find('span').html(sign)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a JsFiddle version for you to look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUTTK/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".pad").hide();

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next(".pad").slideToggle(500);

        if (jQuery(this).find('.span1').is(':visible')){
            jQuery(this).find('.span1').hide();
            jQuery(this).find('.span2').show();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('.span2').hide();
            jQuery(this).find('.span1').show();       
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<h3 class="heading">text1
    <span class="span1" style="float: right;">&#8744;</span>
    <span class="span2" style="float: right; display: none;">&#8743;</span>
</h3>
<div class="pad">content</div>

<h3 class="heading">text1
    <span class="span1" style="float: right;">&#8744;</span>
    <span class="span2" style="float: right; display: none;">&#8743;</span>
</h3>
<div class="pad">content</div>
```